# How to remove Backslash from the middle of a string

Tags: javascript

The usernames used by my organization are in the following format:

> i:4#.w|abcd\1231231234.abc

I need to remove the \ and everything before it using JavaScript. I have the following code but because of the escape function of the \ in JS I find that JS simply remove \13 from the string. I have search for hours and haven't been able to find any solution. Here is the current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function () {
       document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML ="i:4#.w|abmy\1391251254.abc";
   }
</script>

<div>
    <span id="userId"></span>
</div>
```

I need the result to be 1391251254.abc

Comment: How are you creating that string? because "\" is a special character.

Comment: hardcoded, The string is the format for the userID my organization uses. although I modified it slightly of course in order to post it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the last part of your string. It will work event if the string contains more than one backslash.

```js
var string = "i:4#.w|abmy\\1391251254.abc"; //Note the escaped '\'

var regex = /.*?\\(.*)$/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
console.log(match[1]); //1391251254.abc
```

Comment: SystemGlitch, Thank you, I liked your answer but I don't have the rep for it to count. You solution worked perfectly though. Thanks again everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `substring` along with the function `lastIndexOf`.

```
var str = "i:4#.w|abmy\\1391251254.abc"
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1)
```